# Event on clicking dynamic elements in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to retrieve categories words (dynamically generated) from a DB, then append to the container html using jQuery. This generates the following content in the body;

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="answer" id="opt1">Castle</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt2">Plate</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt3">Boy</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt4">Generous</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
```

My aim is to then check for a mouse click on any of the words (Castle, Plate etc.), and launch an event, say an alert for example. For this, I try the following script;

```
$('.answer').click (function () {
    alert("Hi");  //My Real goal - alert(this.id)
})
```

However, this does nothing. If I run the following code though;

```
$('#container').click (function () {
    alert("Hi");
})
```

I get a pop-up on clicking any of the words. But in this case, I cannot retrieve 'this.id'. I'm not really understanding what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please explain it to me?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7s4m88s/)

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You are missing a closing brace in your second code.

Comment: Are the elements added to the page dynamically after load? Also, your first example is missing a `}`

Comment: Its a typo. Thanks.

Comment: the braces are still in the wrong order, but with that fixed your code seems to work absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/srdeok5b/

Comment: Ooops. Yeah, failed to notice that. And yes, it would work in jsfiddle, since we're not generating the elements dynamically there. In my original code though, I generate it based on random words retrieved off a DB. Didn't wanna show all of that mess here. Thanks Rory x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> retrieve categories words (dynamically generated) from a DB, then append to the container html

Sounds like you are trying to bind events before answer items are appended to HTML. In this case, simplest and the most efficient solution is to delegate events to parent container:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.answer', function () {
  alert("Hi");
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly. All of you were right about the issue when I was creating the elements dynamically. Chose this as the answer, since its directly related to my code. x)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).attr("id")` to get the current `Id` of the element you click on

As other mention, You have to use `.on('click'` if you create the element dynamically

```js
$('body').on('click','.answer',function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));  //My Real goal - alert(this.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="answer" id="opt1">Castle</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt2">Plate</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt3">Boy</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt4">Generous</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If the OP claims `this.id` doesn't work, I'm not sure that `$(this).attr('id')` would either as they're logically the same thing

Comment: You missed the point of the question. Plus `this.id` is the same as `$(this).attr("id")`.

Comment: You were right about your explanation on elements created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="answer" id="opt1">Castle</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt2">Plate</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt3">Boy</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="answer" id="opt4">Generous</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>

<script>
$('#container').on('click','.answer',function(){
alert(this.id);
})
</script>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I got it wrong way :) i hope it will be ok @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for you create answers dynamically. 
You can try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".answer", function() {
   alert(this.id)
});
```

Comment: Delegating to document is a overkill, since `#container` is available at the time of event binding.

Comment: I see. Do you have another tip?

Comment: It works, except for the fact like @dsfq mentioned, using #container would be fine. Thank you x)

Answer (score 0):

Try this **event.target**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".answer").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

});

From here you can apply various operation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#container').on('click', '.answer', function () {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
})
```